# ReactNative Animated width of a view doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I want to animate a view's width change in React Native. It's the `theWidth` value below:

```
class MyView extends Component {

  state = {
    theWidth: new Animated.Value(10),
  }

  compontentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.theWidth,
      {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 10000,
      }
    ).start();
  }
  render() {
    let { theWidth } = this.state;
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          ...this.props.style,
          width: theWidth,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}

      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MyView style={{ width: 550, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 28, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10 }}>Fa2ding in1</Text>
        </MyView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Seems the width value (`theWidth`) hasn't changed. How to debug this?

Comment: just a simple typo... it's componentDidMount not compontentDidMount... You can use react native debugger to catch these small errors.

Comment: @needsleepThanks, this mistake is stupid. I used debugger but only  some warnings I can't see errors. Also may I ask any way to check type in case stupid error like this? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't get any errors because this is not an error actually, it is treated as a new property. You can use a simple console.log to see if the block of your code is executed but normally I would catch this in my IDE or with a linter. I use Webstorm and every time I type a function that is not used it is underlined so I get the hint that there is something wrong there. With a linter and a no unused vars you would get the same helpful message I think. Anyway this is indeed a frustrating mistake :)